# Can i remove dvd drive in thinkpad w510 and attach new HD

Tags: thinkpad, compact-disc

I have thinkpad w510.
Someone told me that i can remove my dvd drive and can attach new harddrive there.

How can i do that

Answer (score 3):

You can buy a bay like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000E0KGU0) which goes to DVD-ROM place. It should work with any 2.5" SATA hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

This could be possible if its a sata connection, but you will not have the bay to hold the hard drive.

Comment: can i buy the bay which can fit in cd drive space